# In swing, how do you add a hotkey without a menu item?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

For most shortcuts, I add the action to the toplevel JMenu and provide the shortcut to the JMenuItem using `setAccelerator(..)`.  How do I make a global shortcut for an action without adding it to the menu?

Comment: Good design dictates that an application menu provide access to *every* function of the application. See _About Face 3: The Essentials of Interaction Design_ by Alan Cooper.

Comment: I absolutely agree at least 99-and-a-half % of the time, and I'm glad you made the point and gave the reference.  (I'm adding a hidden developer/tester shortcut at the moment.)

Comment: It's a good use case. You've proven it again: There are absolutely no absolutes in software development.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001899/), but I had trouble finding it because I was asking it differently.

As pointed out there, look for `getInputMap` / `getActionMap` in [the Java keybindings tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

I'll finish writing the question and mark it as a duplicate in case it helps to find it.